# Configure Kubernetes bitnami/mariadb container to mount minikube volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mariadb, bitnami, minikube

I've been hitting errors when trying to set up a dev platform in Kubernetes & minikube. The config is creating a **service**, **persistentVolume**, **persistentVolumeClaim** & **deployment**.

The  **deployment** is creating a single **pod** with a single **container** based on `bitnami/mariadb:latest`

I am mounting a local volume into the **minikube** vm via:

`minikube mount <source-path>:/data`

This local volume is mounting correctly and can be inspected when I ssh into the minikube vm via: `minikube ssh`

I now run:

`kubectl create -f mariadb-deployment.yaml`

to fire up the platform, the yaml config:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mariadb-deployment
  labels:
    app: supertubes
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: supertubes
    tier: mariadb
  type: LoadBalancer
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-db-pv
  labels:
    type: local
    tier: mariadb
    app: supertubes
spec:
  storageClassName: slow
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/staging/sumatra/mariadb-data"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-db-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: supertubes
spec:
  storageClassName: slow
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: local
      tier: mariadb
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: mariadb-deployment
  labels:
    app: supertubes
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: supertubes
      tier: mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: supertubes
        tier: mariadb
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      containers:
      - image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
        name: mariadb
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: <db-password>
        - name: MARIADB_DATABASE
          value: <db-name>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mariadb
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mariadb-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /bitnami
      volumes:
      - name: mariadb-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: local-db-pv-claim
```

The above config will then fail to boot the **pod** and inspecting the pods logs within `minikube dashboard` shows the following:

```
nami    INFO  Initializing mariadb
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Cleaning data dir...
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Configuring permissions...
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Validating inputs...
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Initializing database...
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Creating 'root' user with unrestricted access...
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Creating database pw_tbs...
mariadb INFO  ==&gt; Enabling remote connections...
Error executing 'postInstallation': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/bitnami/mariadb'
```

Looking at the above I believed the issue was to do with Bitnami using user: 1001 to launch their mariadb image:

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues/134

Since reading the above issue I've been playing with `securityContext` within the **containers** spec. At present you'll see I have it set to:

*deployment.template.spec*

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 1001
```

but this isn't working. I've also tried:

```
securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

but didn't get anywhere with that either.

One other check I made was to remove the volumeMount from *deployment.template.spec.containers* and see if things worked correctly without it, **which they do :)**

I then opened a shell into the pod to see what the permissions on `/bitnami` are:

[image]

Reading a bit more on the Bitnami issue posted above it says the user: 1001 is a member of the root group, therefore I'd expect them to have the neccessary permissions... At this stage I'm a little lost as to what is wrong.

If anyone could help me understand how to correctly set up this minikube vm volume within a container that would be amazing!

### Edit 15/03/18

Following @Anton Kostenko's suggestions I added a **busybox** container as an `initContainer` which ran a `chmod` on the `bitnami` directory:

```
...
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["chmod", "-R", "777", "/bitnami"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mariadb-persistent-storage
      mountPath: /bitnami
  containers:
  - image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    name: mariadb
...
```

however even with setting global **rwx** permissions (777) the directory couldn't mount as the MariaDB container doesn't allow user 1001 to do so:

```
nami    INFO  Initializing mariadb
Error executing 'postInstallation': EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/bitnami/mariadb/.restored'
```

### Another Edit 15/03/18

Have now tried setting the user:group on my local machine (MacBook) so that when passed to the **minikube** vm they should already be correct:

[image]

Now `mariadb-data` has rwx permission for eveyone and user: 1001, group: 1001

I then removed the initContainer as I wasn't really sure what that would be adding.

SSHing onto the minikube vm I can see the permissions and user:group have been carried across:

[image]

The user & group now being set as **docker**

Firing up this container results in the same sort of error:

```
nami    INFO  Initializing mariadb
Error executing 'postInstallation': EIO: i/o error, utime '/bitnami/mariadb/.restored'
```

I've tried removing the **securityContext**, and also adding it as runAsUser: 1001, fsGroup: 1001, however neither made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is an issue in [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1990).

You can try to use the [init-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) which will fix a permissions before main container will be started, like this:

```
  ...........
    spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: "fix-non-root-permissions"
    image: "busybox"
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
    command: [ "chmod", "-R", "g+rwX", "/bitnami" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: datadir
      mountPath: /bitnami
    containers:
  .........
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, however, the `/bitnami` directory already has group permissions of rwx. I'm not too sure I get the use cases for initContainers yet though so perhaps I'm missing something? Do they not create a separate container, run some commands, then exit, therefore when the main container (mariadb) is fired up its `/bitnami` directory would have whatever permissions were set on that docker image?

Comment: Welcome. Yes, the _InitContainer_ is a container which running before your main application for prepare environment as an example. It will create a separate container, but because it can use the same volume\dirctory (see volumeMounts) you can do whatever you want with it. So, it is something like initialization script which will start every time when you Kubernetes running your pod. You can actually try to use it, I think you have a big chance that it will help because it will run `chmod` on exactly same volume which you claim for DB, not just on host directory.

Comment: Anyway, it works with other bitnami containers, which has the same problem:)

Comment: had a go with this method last night but sadly it didn't help - still had permission errors when booting the MariaDB container. Not too sure what to do at this point - may look at just running docker-compose for dev work and Kubernetes only in production.

Comment: Did you add also a chown to the command, like: `command: [ "chown", "-R", "1001:1001", "/bitnami" ]`? You can just add another one init container to the array with different command.

Comment: I've tried doing it on the busybox but it wasn't allowed to, so I set the user:group `1001:1001` on my local machine. Still not getting anywhere:

Comment: `Error executing 'postInstallation': EIO: i/o error, utime '/bitnami/mariadb/.restored'`